# Problema con subentidad en JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Buenas tardes tengo una aplicacion que usa JPA. El problema es que necesito cambiar el flujo de una función donde se trae tanto la entidad principal como las subentientidades

```
entityManager().find(Padre.class, id);
```

Está `Padre.class` tiene definida como hija esta clase `Hija.class`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hija")
private Set<Hija> hijas;
```

Ademas de tener muchisimas mas subentidades.

Como podría hacer para filtrar esta `Hija.class` en el momento de la  llamada `entityManager().find(Padre.class, id);` para solo traerme cierta parte de la `Hija.class`

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En este caso tendrás que escribir una consulta (query), suponiendo que quieras filtrar a las hijas por nombre:

```
TypedQuery<Padre> q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Padre p WHERE p.hija.nombre= :nombre", Padres.class);
q1.setParameter("nombre", nombre);
q1.getResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes realizar con CriteriaQuery

```
CriteriaQuery<Hija> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Hija.class);

Root<Hija> root = countQuery.from(Hija.class);
Join<Hija, Padre> padre =  root.join("relacion", JoinType.INNER);

criteriaQuery.where(                
            builder.equal(padre.get("relacion"), filtro));
```